# Locking styles in Word using VBA to restrict new styles

Tags: vba, ms-word, styles, paste

I am new to using VBA, please forgive my ignorance.
I understand we can restrict users from adding new styles via 'Manage Styles.' But I need a msg like the below, for the user to understand why paste didn't work. Not sure why this isn't working. Please advise.

```
Sub EditPaste()
Dim k As Long

Options.PasteFormatBetweenDocuments = wdMatchDestinationFormatting
Options.PasteFormatBetweenStyledDocuments = wdUseDestinationStyles
k = ActiveDocument.Styles.Count
Selection.Range.Paste
If k <> ActiveDocument.Styles.Count Then
    ActiveDocument.Undo
    MsgBox "Paste unsuccessful. You tried to introduce new styles."
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested your code in Office 365 and it is working. What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Timothy, sorry about this delayed reply. Yes, it is working on the new documents but for some reasons it is not working on the existing template that I am trying to restrict users from adding new styles to.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "template". This term has special meaning in Word but is commonly misused.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you on this, thanks for your reply. My effort needs to cross 2 levels. Level 1: Test on MS word with built-in styles - the macro works well. Level 2: Test on document with our styles (which I call a template) - the macro is not working well. While it picks the 'normal' from our style, it gives no message.

Comment: I suggest that you create a template for your users from the document that you are currently using. The template should then be made available from a network folder that users only have read-only access to. That way you can prevent users from saving changes to the template. If you set that folder as the "Workgroup templates" location users can create new documents from the template using File New.

Comment: Requesting everyone to help me get this code working:

Comment: Hi Timothy, many thanks for your kind reply. One last request, I just found this new code that covers all Paste-Options like the above. Please help me understand why this is giving me errors. Sub PasteClean()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
      DataType:=wdPasteText, _
      Placement:= wdInLine, _
      DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub

Comment: I have tried that code and do not get any errors. You should either ask a new question or edit this one as you need to provide more information. Please refer to the site help section on How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Alright, I will go through the Help section. Thanks for your time.