# How to prevent styles from being introduced into the destination document when pasting from other documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have set up a MS Word Document (.docx) for my colleagues to use with boilerplate text and neatly sorted styles to choose from the style gallery. Problem is, they often paste from other documents  thereby introducing new styles into the template. Restricting them to a few styles via the formatting restrictions is no option since this also disables font formatting. The following code (partly taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727591/locking-styles-in-word-using-vba-to-restrict-new-styles)) kinda does what I want but might there be a better option?

```
Sub EditPaste()
'PURPOSE: Prevent styles from other documents from being introduced into this document.
    
    Dim k As Long

    k = ActiveDocument.Styles.Count
    
    Selection.Range.Paste
    If k <> ActiveDocument.Styles.Count Then
        ActiveDocument.Undo
        On Error GoTo F
            Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
            DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:=wdInLine, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False
    Exit Sub

F:  MsgBox ("An error has occurred.")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are turning this document into a DOCM? Otherwise, where are you planning on putting the EditPaste subroutine? If you put it the users Normal template it effects all of their documents. If your document relies on a custom template, you did not mention that and its important to know.

Comment: @RichMichaels Apologies for omitting this detail. Yes, if VBA serves as the solution I would turn the document into an DOCM or DOTM and place the subroutine within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't intercept the standard paste command. Pasting formatted content like tables or fields won't work. Instead, use a macro that has an alternate key combination like **Alt + V** to run a macro like this:

```
Sub PasteUnformattedText()
  On Error GoTo ClipboardNotText
    Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    Exit Sub
ClipboardNotText:
  Err.Clear
  On Error GoTo ClipboardNotUnicodeText
  Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=22 'Paste Unicode Text
  Exit Sub
ClipboardNotUnicodeText:
  Selection.Paste
  Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. This seems like a sensible solution but requires user discipline to never use standard paste in the same way manually pasting values would. For my use case this is not strict enough - users must automatically be prevented from introducing new styles into the document.